# Building angular 10 with ng build --prod throws Error: Expected a pseudo-class or pseudo-element

Tags: css, angular

The log points to styles.b65fa47c6505fedc901a.css:1252:1 in my repo but I dont see this file. This only happens when I build, not when I do ng serve.
Anyone knows how to track this error? I have many css files; there must be a way to identify where the problem is.

Comment: Could be due to some formatting issues withing css, for example make sure you have spaces after your styles like so: `top: 0px` *NOT* `top:0px`

Comment: If you are using SASS with the indentation syntax then always have a space after the property name as Dylan Anlezark has mentioned above. But I would strongly recommend to use SCSS instead for avoiding such minor errors

Comment: So there's no easy way to identify which file has the error?